# How can I change my code so that the model's output is consistent with the known expected behaviour?

Tags: python, differential-equations

I am working on a project for my differential equations class that requires us to take an existing model and put it in python.

I have found a system that models the spread of disease with realistic parameters. However, using the code I wrote, the model does not behave as expected. For one, some of my graphs exceed the total population... I don't know what to change or if I could restrict them in a way to still respect the dynamics of the system.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def seiqr_model(y, t, vinv, beta1, beta2, sigma1, sigma2, sigma3, r, d1, d2, alpha, eta1, eta3):
  S, E, I, R, Q = y
  dSdt = vinv - d1*S - alpha*vinv/d1 * E
  dEdt = ((alpha*vinv - d1 *eta1)/d1) * E
  dIdt = r*E - eta3*I
  dRdt = sigma3*E + sigma2*I - d1*R + sigma1*Q
  dQdt = beta1*E + beta2*I - eta3*Q
  return[dSdt, dEdt, dIdt, dRdt, dQdt]


# initial cond.
S0 = 34218169
E0 = 10000
I0 = 157
R0 = 0
Q0 = 0
y0 = [S0, E0, I0, R0, Q0,]

#parameters
vinv = 2300
beta1 = 0.15
beta2 = 0.00001
sigma1 = 0.00001
sigma2 = 0.00001
sigma3 = 0.001
r = 0.00325
d1 = 0.00003
d2 = 0.0000003423
alpha = 0.00000000264
eta1 = r+beta1+sigma3+d1
eta3 = sigma1+d1+d2


t = np.linspace(0, 75, 75)

sol = odeint(seiqr_model, y0, t, args=(vinv, beta1, beta2, sigma1, sigma2, sigma3, r, d1, d2, alpha, eta1, eta3))

plt.plot(t, sol[:,0], label='S')
plt.plot(t, sol[:,1], label='E')
plt.plot(t, sol[:,2], label='I')
plt.plot(t, sol[:,3], label='R')
plt.plot(t, sol[:,4], label='Q')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Proportion')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Shouldn't `dEdt` have a dependency on `S`? Otherwise the number of people in the Exposed state has no relation to the remaining susceptibles - which would be one explanation for the behaviour you see.

Comment: Generally, as a sanity check, it would be useful to track `S + E + I + R + Q` at each time step and validate that it's equal to `S0 + E0 + I0 + R0 + Q0`, i.e. the total population is partitioned exactly into these five groups.